# Add a dragable marker after geocoder result in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: angular, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to add a dragable marker after a geocoder result in Mapbox GL JS and set up a `dragend` event. I need this so the user can drag the marker in the exact location he wants.

This is the tutorial I've followed: [Set a point after Geocoder result](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/point-from-geocoder-result/)

With this tutorial I could add the marker with the dragable option, but I don't know how I can add the `dragend` event to the marker.

```
 var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
      accessToken: Mapboxgl.accessToken,
      language: 'pt-BR',
      marker: {
        draggable: true,
        color: 'red'
      },
      placeholder: 'Pesquise por cidade, rua, bairro ou CEP',
      mapboxgl: Mapboxgl
  });
```

I tried creating a marker and setting it to the marker property, but without success:

```
const marker = new Mapboxgl.Marker({      
  draggable: true
});

marker.on('dragend', () => {
  console.log(marker.getLngLat());
});

var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
  accessToken: Mapboxgl.accessToken,
  language: 'pt-BR',
  marker: marker,
  placeholder: 'Pesquise por cidade, rua, bairro ou CEP',
  mapboxgl: Mapboxgl
});
```

Any ideas how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried your approach and it also didnt work out my way. I guess the GeoCoder-Marker is  not meant to be dragged at all. However its possible to catch the geocoder result in the following way:

```
geocoder.on('result', function(e) {
  console.log(e.result.center);
  geocoder.clear();
  var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({ draggable: true, color: "pink" })
    .setLngLat(e.result.center)
    .addTo(map)
});
```

The result of the event has the center attribute which can be used to create a new marker at the same position. You can make the marker draggable and add your own popup. Make sure to have a look at the event result and check if it contains any valueable information for you. `geocoder.clear()` removes the result from the map but also from the text field.

I created a fiddle for you where you can see the script in action: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pnxu2joz/4/)

Comment: You're the best. Thank you very much.

Comment: For some reason the geocoder.clear(); line didn't work for me because the clear method wasn't recognized. Maybe it's a version issue, because I just removed that line and your example worked great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@Lukas You are right. Here is some modification, which disable that Geolocation marker option. So, geocoder.clear() option is not required and main thing it doesn't remove the value from text box. Check the below code snippet

```
var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
      accessToken: Mapboxgl.accessToken,
      marker: false,
      mapboxgl: Mapboxgl
  });
```

Here, marker: false is the main thing.

```
geocoder.on('result', function(e) {
  var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({ draggable: true, color: "pink" })
    .setLngLat(e.result.center)
    .addTo(map)
});
```

So, geocoder.clear(); not required anymore.